# How to make a squared border around a form tag

Tags: html, css, border

I want to make a squared border around this html form tag, like a box

```css
.main-form{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid red;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="main-form">
  <input type="text" class="first name" placeholder="Please type your first name!" required>
  <input type="text" class="last name" placeholder="Please type your last name!" required>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <input type="text" class="username" placeholder="Please type your username!" required>
  <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="Please type your email!" required>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Please type a password!" required>
  <input type="password" class="password-confirm" placeholder="Please confirm password!" required>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <button class="sign-up-button">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

I added width: 100%; and then tried to reduce the percentage but the inputs move on other rows.

Comment: What are your expectations?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Do you expect something like this? https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/oNVbpaL

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes

Comment: just a suggestion, a form doesnt need so many "pleases", it can make your code smaller and a better looking form if you just type "first name" instead of telling the user exactly what todo :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `position: absolute` and both values `right`  and `left` `0`, you're essentially telling the browser to resize your form to the relative container. If what you want is to add the border around the form with no inner space, remove the `right: 0` prop, or make the form `static` instead of relative.

See the first note on [this article by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#absolute_positioning) for more info using `top`, `right`, `left` and `bottom` to resize absolute blocks.

```css
.main-form{
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid red;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="main-form">
  <input type="text" class="first name" placeholder="Please type your first name!" required>
  <input type="text" class="last name" placeholder="Please type your last name!" required>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <input type="text" class="username" placeholder="Please type your username!" required>
  <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="Please type your email!" required>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Please type a password!" required>
  <input type="password" class="password-confirm" placeholder="Please confirm password!" required>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <button class="sign-up-button">Sign up</button>
</form>
```